# mxmlc/fcsh ignoring [SWF(width="550", height="400", ...)]

Tags: apache-flex, flash, mxmlc

I'm compiling an .as file using fcsh, which uses it mxmlc.

I use the following shell:

```
mxmlc /Users/johannesjensen/Desktop/Doodler.as -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true
```

But when I get the .swf on my desktop it's dimensions are 500x375 and framerate is 24 when I told it that it needs to be 550x400 and framerate needs to be 120 using

```
[SWF(width="550", height="400", frameRate="120", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]
```

High framerate because it's a drawing app

Any ideas why it ignores the [SWF()] thing?

I'm using Flash Player 10.1 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4 Snow Leopard

Comment: or does this fit better on superuser?

Comment: No, this is a good question for here; as it relates to compiling Flex apps; which is clearly a programming issue.  I'm unclear where you're putting the ["SWF()]" thing, though.

Comment: It's right after the package { part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search reveals that the SWF Metadata tag need to be before the class definition, but after the imports.  It sounds like you're putting it before the imports.

Source:

http://blog.madebyderek.com/archives/2007/01/12/as3-projects-and-the-swf-metadata-tag/

Keep in mind this is an undocumented metadata tag.  I had never heard of it before now.  So I can't guarantee that this information is accurate.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! Pretty weird rule though, but nonetheless, it works. :)

Comment: Aha.  Thanks.  Perhaps an errata for the book I was trying to learn from (O'Reilly's ActionScript 3 Cookbook) which said it can go either before or after the imports is in order. :)